# Automating DBCC CHECKDB

Tags: sql-server, database

I am currently trying to script a job on SQL Server 2005 that will automate the DBCC CHECKDB process.  Basically, I am using a cursor to run through and run DBCC CHECKDB on every database on an instance.  Sometimes it works, running through every database and logging the errors in a table I have designed for that purpose and sometimes it only runs through a few of the databases and stop.  Does anyone have any idea what is going on?  I have included the code that I use for the cursor.

```
DECLARE @DbName varchar(100)

DECLARE
  GetDbName CURSOR
    LOCAL
    FORWARD_ONLY
    OPTIMISTIC
      FOR
         SELECT
           name
         FROM
           sys.databases
         ORDER BY
           name 

  OPEN GetDbName
  FETCH NEXT FROM GetDbName
  INTO @DbName
    WHILE (@@fetch_status = 0)
      BEGIN

        print @DbName

        INSERT INTO
          TempLog
        EXEC('DBCC CHECKDB ('+ @DbName +') WITH NO_INFOMSGS, TABLERESULTS')

        FETCH NEXT FROM GetDbName
        INTO @DbName

      END
CLOSE GetDbName
DEALLOCATE GetDbName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors of a [sufficiently high (20+) severity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937483%28SQL.80%29.aspx) -- in my experience these are most often corruptions such as invalid text pointers -- will stop whatever SQL job is currently running with extreme prejudice, ignoring try/catch constructs and killing the connection.  I would suggest moving this task out to an external process with a new connection for each `DBCC CHECKDB` command so that it can continue in the face of high-severity errors.

Comment: +1 that's most likely the problem. Severe errors also go to errorlog and system event log so is easy to check them there.

Answer (score 0):

use the undocumented sp_MSforeachdb stored proc

```
exec sp_msforeachdb 'use ?; dbcc checkdb'
```

Comment: That is what I used in the beginning.  It has the same problem

Comment: OK wasn't sure if that would bomb out the same as a cursor (even though under the covers that's probably what it is!)

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was actually thinking!